# Button clicked, sound plays, but the button disappears

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Like I said in the title. I want different sounds to play but for some reason the text on the button goes away after the sound plays. Button still works though. I need the button to remain intact.

ALSO is there anyway to not make the page reload when the button is clicked?

Here is my code:

javascript:

```
function playSound() {
    var sounds = new Array(
    "battle.mp3"
);

$("button").html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*(sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
```

HTML

```
<div id="element">
<button onclick="javascript:playSound()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the button is going away because you are replacing its HTML with the embed code.  Have you tried instead creating a different element (such as a div) and targeting that element instead?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be replacing the HTML content inside the button element in your `playSound` function  (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)).  Try embedding it in some other element, like a placeholder `div`.

For not reloading the page, return `false` from your `playSound()` function

Comment: If I do that though that new element will just disappear after it is clicked won't it? Also I put return false; at the end of the function but the page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guys have said you are replacing the element.  Try changing the javascript to:

```
function playSound() {
    var sounds = new Array("battle.mp3");

    $("#soundDiv").html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*(sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");

    return false;
}
```

And the html to:

```
<div id="element">
    <div id="soundDiv"></div>
    <button onclick="javascript:playSound()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That element disappeared as well :(

Comment: It still disappeared. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: My bad didnt close the soundDiv div tag try that.  In general this isn't a very good way to do it as the playSound javascript function that you have written in global scope.  Although scoping javascript correctly is a much deeper topic.

Comment: It still goes away. Is there a better way to go about all of this? I don't understand why it goes away.

Comment: Kevin's example sure should work.  and the `return false` bit should work as well.  Are you sure you're getting a fresh version of the page after your edits?  As a dummycheck, have you done a quick visual change to the static HTML and made sure that shows up?

Comment: It worked. Cleared the cache. One minor thing is that the button seems to jump down after the initial click. Is this a javascript thing or a css issue?

Comment: That's because the content of the div tag above the button is changing as you are putting this new element in there.